# Multiple drawing canvases on one page

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a web page that allows a visitor to draw in multiple canvases on the same page. I've searched all over and can't find a good tutorial. This is what I have so far.

---

```
var mousePressed = false;
var lastX, lastY;
var ctx;

    function InitThis() {
    ctx = document.getElementById('room1').getContext("2d");

    $('#room1').mousedown(function (e) {
        mousePressed = true;
        Draw(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left, e.pageY - $(this).offset().top, false);
    });

    $('#room1').mousemove(function (e) {
        if (mousePressed) {
            Draw(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left, e.pageY - $(this).offset().top, true);
        }
    });

    $('#room1').mouseup(function (e) {
        mousePressed = false;
    });

    $('#room1').mouseleave(function (e) {
        mousePressed = false;
    });
    }

    function Draw(x, y, isDown) {
        if (isDown) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = $('#penColor').val();
        ctx.lineWidth = "4";
        ctx.lineJoin = "round";
        ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;
}

function clearArea() {
    // Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
}
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: The answer seems so simple I must be missing something :-/ Why not just add <canvas id=room2></canvas>, <canvas id=room3></canvas> etc to your page and listen to events on those canvases too?

Answer (score 0):

You can place multiple `<canvas>` elements on your page. Each canvas has its own context, so having a global `ctx` variable doesn't make much sense anymore.

Your event handlers would first need to get the context of the canvas the event happened on using `this.getContext("2d")`.

When you modify any of your drawing-functions to take the context as a function parameter, you can easily use the same function for all your canvases.